# Spam sent to 100 plus contacts in yahoo

Tags: spam-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent Sending Spam with my Yahoo Account?](https://superuser.com/questions/413734/prevent-sending-spam-with-my-yahoo-account)

Over 100 spam emails were sent from my yahoo account.  They do not appear in the sent folder.  I changed my password, etc. and have run scans on my computer.  My real question is if they most likely accessed email addresses or could they have accessed additional information from folders in my email account or saved in my email.  And, how can I tell?

Answer (score 1):

If they are not showing in your sent items, it's probably email spoofing... to send nasty  stuff out to people.

---

Wikipedia - The sender information shown in e-mails (the "From" field) can be spoofed easily. This technique is commonly used by spammers to hide the origin of their e-mails and leads to problems such as misdirected bounces (i.e. e-mail spam backscatter).

E-mail address spoofing is done in quite the same way as writing a forged return address using snail mail. As long as the letter fits the protocol, (i.e. stamp, postal code) the SMTP protocol will send the message. It can be done using a mail server with telnet.[2]

---

So basically there is not a lot you can do but hope it stops or change you email address.